# Diz-se "Foi introduzido no Jornal 2 a pesquisa de clientes" ou "Foi introduzida no Jornal 2 a pesquisa de clientes"?

Tags: verbos, concordância-verbal

Qual a forma correta?

"Foi introduzido no Jornal 2 a pesquisa de clientes" ou "Foi introduzida no Jornal 2 a pesquisa de clientes"?

Possivelmente a segunda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você colocar a ordem assim: A pesquisa de clientes foi introduzida etc.

Dá para ver que a frase é passiva, então concorda com a pesquisa. Agora, pode voltar à ordem que estava: Foi introduzid**a** no Jornal 2 **a** pesquisa de clientes.

Tambem é possível usar: Se introduziu a pesquisa de clientes no Jornal 2. etc.